query on mongoexport not return the correct result using date function
I am trying to extract the data from mongo database using mongoexport in shell (linux) but the extracted data did not match the where condation that i pass on the query :
below is sample of the value of date column on the table :
"createdDate":{"$date":"2020-03-09T18:55:09.714Z"}
below is the query and command that i use :
isodate=$(date -d '-1 day' '+%Y-%m-%d')

mongoexport --uri "mongodb://user_name:password@my_ip:my_port/my_db_name?ssl=false&authSource=admin" --collection=Test -q '{"createdDate": {"$gte": { "$date": "'${isodate}'T00:00:00.000Z" }, "$lte": { "$date": "'${isodate}'T23:59:59.999Z" }}}' --out=$data_path/${run_date}/test.json 

it extracted records have date values like 2020-03-09T18:55:09.714Z which are not match the where  condation I put in the above query
the values that I get is out the range of d-1 date that I used i am getting record related to 2020 year while d-1 in 2024 year

Try --query='{"createdDate... - perhaps it helps. In general it should work, I don't see anything wrong.
